# Derivative of Inverse hyperbolic functions $\tanh^{-1} x$ and $\coth^{-1}$ are the same, So which one to choose for this differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x(y^2-1)}{2(x-2)(x-1)}$

I separated the variables, this is the outcome.

$\int \frac{1}{y^2-1} dy = \int\frac{x}{2(x-2)(x-1)} dx$

Solving the LHS: $-\int \frac{1}{-y^2+1} dy = \tanh^{-1}$y

however, this works as well $-\int \frac{1}{-y^2+1} = \coth^{-1} y$

I looked up online and it says that for $\tanh^{-1}$, $x < 1$ and for $\coth^{-1}$, $x>1$

The domain for $\frac{1}{y^2-1}$ includes $y$ values that are smaller than $1$ and also bigger than $1$, it only doesn't include $1$ as it will be undefined. So how do we determine whether it is $\tanh^{-1}$ or the latter?

Additionally, from $-\tanh^{-1} y = -\frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1-y}{1+y}$

This answer is wrong. The integral is $y= \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{y-1}{y+1} $

What is wrong with my subsequent step?

Comment: Is there a typo in the differential equation in the first line? Otherwise, I don't understand where the $y^2 - 1$ term comes from. Assuming the RHS is missing a factor of $y^2 - 1$, the short answer is that you cannot divide by $y^2 - 1$ if $y = \pm 1$.

Comment: @Ramanujan edited!

Comment: This is similar to the case  $\int dy/y$ where you get $\ln(y)$ when $y>0$ and $\ln(-y)$ when $y<0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the separated equation

$$ \int \frac{1}{1-y^2} dy = -\frac{1}{2} \int \left(\frac{2}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right) dx $$

we do get both of these as valid solutions:

$$ \begin{align*}
\tanh^{-1} y &= -\ln|x-2| + \frac{1}{2} \ln|x-1| + C\\
\coth^{-1} y &= -\ln|x-2| + \frac{1}{2} \ln|x-1| + C
\end{align*} $$

If you just want all the solutions over real variables, both are answers.

But remember that for every real $x$, $|\tanh x| < 1$ and $|\coth x| > 1$. So $\tanh^{-1} y$ only makes sense if $|y|<1$, and $\coth^{-1} y$ only makes sense if $|y|>1$. If you have initial conditions $(x_0,y_0)$, you can determine which one gives the right formula by checking whether $|y_0|<1$ or $|y_0|>1$. (You would also simplify $\ln|x-2|=\ln(2-x)$ if $x_0<2$ or $\ln|x-2|=\ln(x-2)$ if $x_0>2$, and similarly for the $|x-1|$ term, and finally find the correct value of $C$.)